# How to connect public-facing Azure Static Web App to a Function app that is secured with a private endpoint

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-virtual-network, azure-static-web-app

I have an Azure static web app (SWA) that calls a "bring your own functions" API (required separation for an API accessing key vault). The Function app is via a private endpoint. I want the SWA to be public-facing, ideally with Enterprise-grade Edge. In order to let the SWA talk to the function app, I established the same private endpoint for the SWA, resulting in a 403 now from the public Internet. How can I allow the SWA to be public facing (and benefit from CDN / Enterprise-grade Edge) while allowing it to connect to the secured Function app? Thanks!

Comment: Is your function app consumption plan or is it an app service plan inside a vnet with a private endpoint?

Comment: It's an app service plan inside a vnet with a private endpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you cannot achieve this requirement using Static Web App and a FunctionApp behind a private endpoint. The 'bring your own functions' feature requires the functions to not have IP restrictions. {1}
If securing your functions behind a private endpoint is a must, you may want to use App Service instead, this way you can use the feature 'VNet Integration. This feature allows you to route outbound traffic privately, using an IP from a subnet of your own VNet. {2}

Please, take a look at the documentation below:

{1}
[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/functions-bring-your-own#security-constraints

{2}
[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-vnet-integration

Comment: Thank you. So if I want a static web app plus function app plus secure key vault, sounds like my best bet is a vnet for the key vault, an exception to allow the Fn app through, and leave the Fn app endpoint as a public (but difficult to guess) URL. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, according to the documentation your FunctionApp needs to be publicly accessible from the network perspective. You can still require an access key to call your function, so even if people have the URL they'll also need to be authenticated to your FunctionApp. 
If my answer helped you, can you please upvote it or mark as answered? Thank you

Comment: Nice answer well explained. Yes it's a current limitation.

Comment: I have since learned that the Function app can be permitted to access the VNet on the outbound side to talk securely to key vault, which is pretty cool.